# Cannot get Ubuntu 22.04.1 to boot from live USB

Tags: boot, usb, 22.04

I'm attempting to run 22.04.1 from a live USB, specifically Release amd64 (20220809.1) on an HP Envy x360 convertible 15-cp0xxx.

I have enabled legacy BIOS and virtual machine settings, as have heard this can cause issues, and am sure the USB drive is ok as I ran my previous recovery ISO from it.

It boots to GRUB and I can select "try or install Ubuntu", but then stops on the loading screen.

The boot text says
Source list entries for this disc are:
deb CDROM:[Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS *Jammy Jellyfish* -Release amd64 (20220809.1)]/jammy main restricted
Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set

at this point it freezes

EDIT- Created the USB under Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS using the "Make startup disk" tool using the desktop-amd64.iso downloaded from the Ubuntu site.

Graphics are AMD Raven, processor is AMD Ryzen 5 2500u with Radeon Vega mobile gfx x8.
WiFi adapter Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac

Comment: how did you create the USB in the first place and under which OS? Please [edit] into your question.

Comment: Please tell us about the graphics chip/card and wifi chip/card. For both of these components, please specify the brand name and model. It can help us help you.

Comment: How long did you wait?  USB2 devices take several minutes to produce the desktop. Startup Disk Creator sometimes has problems with ISOs not of the  running system (18.04).  Try mkusb or even just dd to make an install media.

Comment: I left it a good 30 minutes running and it hadn't progressed beyond the point I mentioned above. Will try mkusb , am presuming that runs from terminal?

Comment: Erased USB, checked ISO file with md5sum, made live USB with this ISO via mkusb, results exactly the same as before.

Comment: look at [this](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=52920#p529724)

Comment: Check the UEFI Settings for anything USB related, sometimes you might need to enable legacy USB support to boot.

Comment: Legacy boot and USB support is enabled, and it boots happily from live USB to other Ubuntu versions.

Comment: If your computer boots happily into Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS I suggest that you use that version of Ubuntu (instead of 22.04.1 LTS). The versions 20.04.x LTS will be supported until April 2025 (5 years from the release), and should be a fair alternative. If still problems, I suggest that you try with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS which will stay with the original kernel series (and its hardware drivers), and should be more likely to continue working until the end of life in April 2025.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going to try now after the update from 20.04.5 failed.

Comment: Good luck with 20.04.5 LTS :-) If problems, start with the 20.04.1 LTS iso file from [this Ubuntu link](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.1/) to keep the original kernel series.